# Open YouTube application from capacitor's app

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm making application using `ionic` with `capacitor`.
I want to open `YouTube` app from my app.
If I get it right I should be able to do it using `App` Plugin that comes with capacitor: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app

Here is my code:

```
App.canOpenUrl({url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + this.dane.id})
      .then(resp => {
        console.log('Can open url: ', resp);
        App.openUrl({url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + this.dane.id});
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Err', err);
      });
```

It says that I can open that url but YouTube app is not opening (as well as browser).

Comment: is this on iOS? Android? web? all?

Comment: For Android only

Answer (score 1):

In capacitor 3 you can to do this, try this example it's works for me

First install

```
npm install @capacitor/app-launcher
npx cap sync
```

Then

```
import {AppLauncher} from '@capacitor/app-launcher';

const {value} = await AppLauncher.canOpenUrl({url: 'com.google.android.youtube'});
if (value) {
   await AppLauncher.openUrl({url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoId'});
}
```